# Proof of the derivative of $x^n$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Can someone please explain why $(x^n)'=n\cdot x^{n-1}$?

Sorry for not writing it in math characters, I'm new here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Note that if $x>0$, then $\ln(x^n)=n\ln(x)$.  Taking the derivative of each side, using $(\ln(t))'=\dfrac{1}{t}$, and the chain rule on the left side,

$$\dfrac{1}{x^n}\cdot(x^n)' = n\cdot\dfrac{1}{x}.$$

Multiplying by $x^n$ on both sides yields $(x^n)'=nx^{n-1}$.

Comment: Simple and clever. Thanks for teaching :)

Comment: Are u really allowed the presume knowledge about the logarithm? Besides, using the algebraic properties of the logarithm uses an approach to the exponential function via powers while the analytical knowledge of the derivative of the logarithm uses an approach of the exponential via  differential equations. But these are on first view to different definitions not conform with each other. That is your argument is cyclic and therefore the proof seems wrong!

Comment: I like that this generalizes to all $n\in\Bbb R-\{0\}$. Of course, you need to know that $x^n$ is differentiable in the first place to use the chain rule, but this approach hints at what the derivative ought to be.

Comment: Thank you for the comment @Freeze_S.  I don't understand all of your comment.  The answer to whether it is circular is that it need not be, and it depends on what definition of the logarithm you are using.  For example, the natural logarithm can be defined to be $\ln(x) = \int_1^x \dfrac{1}{t}\,dt$.  Using this definition (or others) one can prove the formula for the derivative of $\ln$ and the formula for $\ln(x^n)$ without needing to use the derivative of $x^n$.

In any case, I don't recommend this as a first introduction to the power rule.

Comment: @Bryan: That is a good point, thank you. That was an assumption I neglected to mention.

Comment: @Jonas: So this definition of the logarithm guarantees you that $\ln(x)'=\frac{1}{x}$ but you cannot deduce from it anymore that $\ln(x^n)=n\ln(x)$ - just go through your argument carefully then there will be a barrier somewhere for example using integration by parts gives you basically nothing: $\ln(x^2)=\int_1^x \frac{1}{t}\frac{1}{t}dt=[\frac{1}{t}\ln(t)]_1^x-\int_1^x ??\ln(t)dt=??$

Comment: Or what do you think?

Comment: @Freeze_S: It is straightforward to show that $\int_1^a \frac1t\,dt=\int_b^{ab}\frac1t\,dt$ for all positive $a$ and $b$, from which it follows that $\ln(ab)=\ln(a)+\ln(b)$.  From this it one can play around to show that $\ln(a^n)=n\ln(a)$ for positive $a$ and rational $n$. To get the case of irrational $n$ requires a continuity argument.

Comment: Ok this one now is a really solid argument, thumbs up!

Answer (score 13):

For any positive integer $n$, consider the following algebraic identity:
$$
\frac{x^n - x_0^n}{x-x_0} = x^{n-1} + x^{n-2}\cdot x_0 + \dots + x\cdot x_0^{n-2} + x_0^{n-1}
$$
When $x \to x_0$, the limit is $n\cdot x_0^{n-1}$.

Comment: I love this answer

Comment: I must say that after some thought put into it, your answer is the most rational and understandable

Answer (score 6):

For $x, h \in \mathbb R$, we have by the binomial theorem
$$ (x+h)^n = \sum_k \binom nk x^{n-k}h^k $$
Hence 
\begin{align*}
  \frac{(x+h)^n - x^n}h &= \frac 1h \sum_{k=1}^n \binom nk x^{n-k}h^{k}\\
   &= nx^{n-1} + h \cdot \sum_{k=2}^n \binom nk x^{n-k}h^{k-2}\\
   &\to nx^{n-1}, \quad h \to 0
\end{align*}

Comment: I like this answer.  I would add that it can generalize to $n$ other than positive integers by rewriting as $x^n\dfrac{1}{h}((1+\frac{h}{x})^n-1)$ and using the binomial series for $(1+\frac{h}{x})^n$ (which is perhaps what Nicky Hekster's hint is suggesting doing).

Comment: Why the downvote. Did I overlook something?

Comment: @Jonas, I was hinting at Martini's proof!

Answer (score 2):

Hint: use the definition of the derivative and Newton's binomial formula.

Answer (score 1):

So you know $f' = \lim \frac{ \Delta f}{\Delta x} $. Now, suppose we are given $f$ and $g$, then  we want $(fg)'$,

$$ (fg)' = \lim_{\Delta x \to 0 } \frac{ f(x + \Delta x)g(x + \Delta x) - f(x)g(x)}{\Delta x} = \lim_{\Delta x \to 0 } \frac{ f(x + \Delta x)g(x + \Delta x) + f(x)g(x + \Delta x) - f(x)g(x + \Delta x) - f(x)g(x)}{\Delta x} = \lim_{\Delta x \to 0 } \frac{ g(x + \Delta x)[f(x + \Delta x) - f(x) ] + f(x)[g( x + \Delta x) - g(x)]}{\Delta x} = f'g + fg'$$

Now, since we have shown this trick, we can use it to show $(x^n)' = nx^{n-1} $
If $n = 1$, then $(x)' = 1 = 1x^{0}$. Suppose $(x^n)' = nx^{n-1} $ is for true for $n$, then

$$(x^{n+1})' = [(x^n)(x)]' = nx^{n-1} x + x^n = (n+1)x^n$$

The problem is now solved by induction. bye bye

Comment: This works if $n$ is a positive integer.

Comment: Z is symmetric .

Comment: I don't know what that means.

Comment: $x^{-n} = (x^{-1})^n$ now apply the trick above

Comment: So you are suggesting using induction to prove the negative integer case?  Sure, that would work.  Or one could use the quotient rule and the case you already showed, or use the product rule applied to the equation $x^n\cdot x^{-n} = 1$.  Then you would have the case of integers.  The notation "$n$" might hint that only integers are desired.

Comment: you are way too formal Jonas

Answer (score 1):

Do you know the Product Rule?  If so, there's a cleaner method than the binomial formula (if not, the binomial formula is your best bet).

You have $x^n = \underbrace{x \cdot x \cdot \dots \cdot x \cdot x}_{n \, \text{ times}}$.  The Product Rule says that the derivative is equal to:

$$\underbrace{(x')\cdot\underbrace{x \cdot x \cdot \dots \cdot x \cdot x}_{n-1 \,\text{ times}} + x \cdot (x') \cdot \underbrace{x \cdot x \cdot \dots \cdot x \cdot x}_{n-2 \, \text{ times}} + \dots + \underbrace{x \cdot x \cdot \dots \cdot x \cdot x}_{n-1 \, \text{ times}}\cdot (x')}_{n \,\text{ total products added together}}$$

We know that $(x') = 1$.  So the above sum is equal to:

$$\underbrace{\underbrace{x \cdot x \cdot \dots \cdot x \cdot x}_{n-1 \,\text{ times}} + \dots + \underbrace{x \cdot x \cdot \dots \cdot x \cdot x}_{n-1 \, \text{ times}}}_{n \,\text{ times}}$$

Which is clearly equal to $nx^{n-1}$.

Comment: This works if $n$ is a positive integer.  (Newton's binomial formula is more general.)

Answer (score 1):

I somewhat like this *short* derivation that exploits the power of the binomial theorem: $$\begin{align*}
\boxed{f(x)=x^n}\quad f'(x)=\lim_{h\to0}\dfrac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}&=\lim_{h\to0}\dfrac{x^n+nx^{n-1}h+\cdots+h^n-x^n}{h}\\ &=\lim_{h\to0}\dfrac{nx^{n-1}h+\mathcal O(h^2)} {h}\\
&=\lim_{h\to0}\dfrac{nx^{n-1}h}h+\dfrac{\mathcal O(h^2)}h \\
&=nx^{n-1}+\lim_{h\to0}\mathcal{O}(h)
\\&=nx^{n-1} \quad {\tiny\blacksquare}
\end{align*}$$

Answer (score 1):

This works when $n\in \mathbb{Z}$ and you know the basic properties of derivative.

Let $n\in \mathbb{N}$ we proceed by induction. When $n=0$, so $x^n$ is a constant and then $(x^n)'=0= nx^{n-1}$. Suppose we have already proven the assertion for $n\ge 0$, then $(x^{n+1})'=(x\cdot x^n)'=x'x^n+(x^n)'x=x^n+nx^{n-1}x=x^n+nx^n=(n+1)x^n$.

If $n<0$ and $x\not =0$, then $(x^n)=(1/x^m)$ where $m=-n$ so $m\in \mathbb{N}$. Then $(1/x^m)'=-(mx^{m-1})/x^{2m}=-mx^{-m-1}$ and so $nx^{n-1}$.